# Issues calling RESTful Glassfish Java web service with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, rest, oauth, glassfish

XSS/CORs is allowed from the Apache web server and I can successfully make calls using query string parameters.

The RESTful service I'm told uses OAuth.

The call to the RESTful web service is trivial with Fiddler via the Composer and returns valid JSON data. I set one Authorization header but the requests look totally different when sent in Fiddler Composer versus setting a header in Ajax.

I've tried with and without the Accept and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers.

This is the request header from Fiddler after executing the request in the Composer.

```
GET {/trailing server URL} HTTP/1.1
Cookies / Login
    Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Transport
    Host: {server URL}
```

And this is my Ajax request

```
$(function () {
    var token = "Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", Accept: "application/json", Authorization: token
        }
        //,
        //beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        //jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        //jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
        //}
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log("Error - textStatus = " + textStatus + " , error = " + error);
        });
});
```

This is the HTTP request headers captured via Fiddler from my Ajax browser request

```
OPTIONS {trailing server URL} HTTP/1.1
Client
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
Cookies / Login
    DNT: 1
Miscellaneous
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,authorization
    Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
    Origin: {local machine URL}
Transport
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: {server URL}
```

Why does the AJAX request header display 'OPTIONS' instead of 'GET' like the Fiddler Composer header?

Why does the Fiddler Composer header show the Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx value under the Cookies / Login section?

I'm hearing that I shouldn't be keeping the token in the JavaScript code because it can be viewed in the browser (in reality, the token would not be hard coded but passed as a variable). How else would I pass the token and keep it secure?

Comment: Yes, also I am seeing that "AJAX request header display 'OPTIONS' instead of 'GET'". Did you find any solution. I am calling restful service api through ajax client.

Comment: No actually abandoned calling the web service through JavaScript and are using C# to more easily keep the token secure.